# Is there a usecase for nested classes?

Tags: c++, python, ruby, oop

I've recently seen several people doing things like this here on Stackoverflow:

```
class A:
    foo = 1

    class B:
        def blah(self):
            pass
```

In other words, they have nested classes. This works (although people new to Python seem to run into problems because it doesn't behave like they thought it would), but I can't think of any reason to do this in any language at all, and certainly not in Python. Is there such a usecase? Why are people doing this? Searching for this it seems it's reasonably common in C++, is there a good reason there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allows you to control the access of the nested class- for example, it's often used for implementation detail classes. In C++ it also has advantages in terms of when various things are parsed and what you can access without having to declare first.

Comment: Ah, of course! *slaps forehead* Python doesn't have access control, it turns out that this part of the original OOP theory was mistaken, private membership is just a hindrance.

Comment: I don't think private membership is a hindrance.  A user of a container class shouldn't be able to access something like `std::map<K,V>::rb_node` or whatever.

Comment: C++ and Python have different underlying design goals in many ways -- it makes sense for Python not to have access control, but the same is not true for C++.

Comment: Perhaps there is a security reason in a low level language like C++. I haven't used it enough to know. But I doubt it, the programmer that uses the class will just find a worse hack with more holes in it instead. :) But private membership has bitten me in Java, and many times in Delphi, which I used for years. I've never once needed it in Python.

Comment: @Lennart: there isn't a security reason. It's purely a way of reminding users of the published API. If you don't want to publish a member, you can mark it private so that the users gets hit around the head with the compiler if they try to use it (or, depending how you look at it, reminded by the compiler that they can't rely on their code to work with the next release, because they've used an unpublished implementation detail). There's nothing to force you to mark anything private in C++ if you don't want to.

Comment: ... but if you're "bitten by" it in C++, because you want to fiddle with internals that the author has reserved, then just as in Python it means really you should fork the code you're using to ensure those details are still present in future.

Comment: You can mark it in Python as well, but with the difference that the programmer will know it's a private implementation detail, but *they can use it anyway*. It' Python it's only convention. In other languages when it's private, you actually stop people from using it.

Comment: When they are not present, you get an error message, and then you can update your code. Why should I be forced to fork the code just because something maybe will change in some distant future? Makes no sense.

Comment: @Lennart: you can, but most people don't. C++ programmers are (trained to be) much more serious about keeping internals internal, perhaps because in C++ your constantly wary of crashing the system. I use both Python and C++, and if I ever had to use a `__` member in Python from outside the class, then I'd probably record it as a bug, and I'd probably regret not fixing it immediately. Potentially useful for debug tracing and the like, but then again in C++ you can usually bodge something for debugging anyway, as in the infamous `#define private public`.

Comment: @Lennart: depends how you do maintenance. The "future" may not be distant, and personally I'd rather design a good interface, than design a bad one that my users will work around, creating work for my users at a time when for all I know they might be busy on something else. Makes no sense to store up bugs, that will hit you on *somebody else's schedule*.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: All of this is good points. And none of it needs to have actual access control. In Python you mark things as private by a leading underscore (two leading underscores does not make it private, it's a misunderstanding). But you can still access it if you must. Now if you'd rather fork the code than access it, that's up to you. But you do not force *others* to do so. In C++/Java/Delphi, then you force them to fork. You are making that decision for them, and you are usually wrong when you do so.

Comment: @Lennart: There is a reason that you completely fail to consider: having a private method, for example, allows you to inline it extremely aggressively - when you compile it. An extremely good reason for forbidding you from calling private members or fields is that, depending on how aggressive the compilation process is, they could literally **not exist**.

Comment: @Lennart: none of it *needs* access control, just as a programming language doesn't *need* static typing (and indeed Python doesn't have that either). People who want to program in a particular style often find it beneficial to use tools (languages or libraries) which enforce that. If you think your tool-authors are making wrong decisions then you're in trouble. That's not specific to access control, although I suppose it gives them one more way to annoy me. Python itself is opinionated in some respects, as are designers of Python interfaces. Just not in this respect.

Comment: @Jean Hominal: That's an interesting reason. @Steve Jessop: The point is that this tool has no benefit in the cases you mention, while the drawbacks are real. Yes, the tool-authors are often making the wrong decisions. If they hadn't, setting things to private wouldn't have bit me.

Comment: Any time you can get into an object's innards and break its invariants, that's a threat to security (depending only on how critical the object in question is to your security policy). To the extent that private membership is effective at preventing someone else from breaking your invariants, private membership enforces security. In Java, where private membership can only be circumvented by reflection if the security manager allows it, private membership **does** enforce security.

Comment: I think the main split is that from the POV of C++ programmers, Python programmers are a bunch of cowboys who'll do anything that works on their machine, whether they're using a guaranteed, documented interface or not. From the POV of Python programmers, C++ programmers spend untold hours fiddling with a bunch of compile-time tests that distort their code beyond sanity, when they could have got the same results with runtime tests if their language didn't lack perfectly normal features like introspection. Since I program both, I think everyone's right to an extent.

Comment: ... but one major factor I think is that the C++ language *expects* programmers to write code that will work on multiple implementations, perhaps with significantly different characteristics. Most Python programmers figure that a Python implementation that doesn't display *precisely the same* behaviour as CPython in all circumstances, is broken. Or anyway dodgy, and you're not that bothered if your code doesn't work on it. So C++ programmers care about guarantees (when writing C++), whereas Python programmers use the source (when writing Python). Some programmers do both.

Comment: ... in practice I think I first wrote Python before I first wrote C++, but nevertheless I cringe at "use the source", especially when voiced by the idle layabout who should have written better documentation for their modules. Fortunately, serious Python stuff is pretty well documented, so you can write Python using only documented behavior, and leave off hacking about with internals in ways that break that encapsulation and introduce Risk. From the C++ POV, if you have to do that you've already lost, so who really cares whether the language allows it? From the Python POV: I need to ship.

Answer (score 6):

The main reason for putting one class in another is to avoid polluting the global namespace with things that are used only inside one class and therefore doesn't belong in the global namespace. This is applicable even to Python, with the global namespace being a namespace of a particular module. For example if you have SomeClass and OtherClass, and both of them need to read something in a specialized way, it is better to have SomeClass.Reader and OtherClass.Reader rather than SomeClassReader and OtherClassReader.

I have never encountered this in C++, though. [It can be problematic to control access to the outer class' fields from a nested class.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/C___Portability_Guide#Be_careful_with_inner_%28nested%29_classes) And it is also pretty common to have just one public class in a compilation unit defined in the header file and some utility classes defined in the CPP file (the Qt library is a great example of this). This way they aren't visible to "outsiders" which is good, so it doesn't make much sense to include them in the header. It also helps to increase binary compatibility which is otherwise a pain to maintain. Well, it's a pain anyway, but much less so.

A great example of a language where nested classes are really useful is Java. Nested classes there automatically have a pointer to the instance of the outer class that creates them (unless you declare the inner class as static). This way you don't need to pass "outer" to their constructors and you can address the outer class' fields just by their names.

Comment: In Python you'd rather put things in modules. There are generally very few things in the global namespace, as the global namespace aren't truly global. So I don't think that is applicable to Python.

Comment: @Lennart, I meant of course the global namespace of a module. I'll edit my answer to correct this. If you have five classes in a module and each one needs to read something in a specialized way, it is usually better to have a Reader nested class in each global class rather than SomeClassReader, OtherClassReader and so on.

Comment: Yeah, in most cases you'd in Python rather have separate modules. But it's a valid answer so you get a +1 anyway. :)

Comment: @Lennart, separate modules for what? For things that don't even belong in the global namespace of the same module? I don't get it. Where would you put the reader for the SomeClass if the SomeClass belongs to the module mymodule, provided that the reader class is only used internally by SomeClass?

Comment: I could say "same module as what"? :-) If you want to separate things from a namespace you typically use separate modules. In this case you'd probably stick each SomeClass in somemodule, instead of mymodule, and then import it to mymodule. Or maybe make mymodule a namespace. But yes, making is a nested class is a valid way of doing it as well. Never seen that actually done though, except by people coming from other languages and are new to Python.

Comment: @Lennart, oh, so are you talking about having somemodule.Reader and othermodule.Reader? I guess that makes sense too. This, by the way, is how I usually see it done in C++, I have no idea why I didn't understand it at first. I think both ways are equally right, but using a nested class is usually better if it is relatively simple _and_ you have a good reason to keep outer classes in one module.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov: Exactly. That's a more common solution than nested classes in Python, although I guess both are "correct" as such.

Comment: Have you never used std::list or std::map. You don;t think these contain a private internal node class that they use to implement the structure internally.

Comment: @Martin, no, I have never used std::list or std::map and never met anyone who used them. I use Qt instead. Now that I look at it, it uses some nested classes too, I just never paid attention to this. But I still wouldn't say it's too common in C++. It's not like Java where almost every program uses them.

Comment: @Sergey: I would say its very common. The difference is that in C++ the code is well enough encapsulated that you don;t even need to know (it just happens without you even realizing).

Answer (score 3):

I am not a big fan of python, but to me this type of decisions are more semantical than syntactical. If you are implementing a list, the class `Node` inside `List` is not a class in itself meant to be used from anywhere, but an implementation detail of the list. At the same time you can have a `Node` internal class inside `Tree`, or `Graph`. Whether the compiler/interpreter allows you to access the class or not is in a different thing. Programing is about writing specifications that the computer can follow and other programers can read, `List.Node` is more explicit in that `Node` is internal to `List` than having `ListNode` as a first level class.

Answer (score 2):

In some languages, the nested class will have access to variables that are in scope within the outer class. (Similarly with functions, or with class-in-function nesting. Of course, function-in-class nesting just creates a method, which behaves fairly unsurprisingly. ;) )

In more technical terms, we create a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Right, and with Pythons explicitness, and explicit self, this also becomes useless in Python as you can access everything from everywhere if you are explicit, and not even your own instances members are accessible implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Python lets you do a lot of things with functions (including lambdas) that in C++03 or Java you need a class for (although Java has anonymous inner classes, so a nested class doesn't always look like your example). Listeners, visitors, that kind of thing. A list comprehension is loosely a kind of visitor:

Python:

```
(foo(x) if x.f == target else bar(x) for x in bazes)
```

C++:

```
struct FooBar {
    Sommat operator()(const Baz &x) const {
        return (x.f == val) ? foo(x) : bar(x);
    }
    FooBar(int val) : val(val) {}
    int val;
};

vector<Sommat> v(bazes.size());
std::transform(bazes.begin(), bazes.end(), v.begin(), FooBar(target));
```

The question that C++ and Java programmers then ask themselves is, "this little class that I'm writing: should it appear in the same scope as the big class that needs to use it, or should I confine it within the scope of the only class that uses it?"[*]

Since you don't want to publish the thing, or allow anyone else to rely on it, often the answer in these cases is a nested class. In Java, private classes can serve, and in C++ you can restrict classes to a TU, in which case you may no longer care too much what namespace scope the name appears in, so nested classes aren't actually required. It's just a style thing, plus Java provides some syntactic sugar.

As someone else said, another case is iterators in C++. Python can support iteration without an iterator class, but if you're writing a data structure in C++ or Java then you have to put the blighters somewhere. To follow the standard library container interface you'll have a nested typedef for it whether the class is nested or not, so it's fairly natural to think, "nested class".

[*] They also ask themselves, "should I just write a for loop?", but let's suppose a case where the answer to that is no...

Answer (score 1):

In C++ at least, one major common use-case for nested classes is iterators in containers.  For example, a hypothetical implementation might look something like this:

```
class list
{
   public:

   class iterator 
   {
      // implementation code
   };

   class const_iterator
   {
      // implementation code
   };
};
```

Another reason for nested classes in C++ would be private implementation details like node classes for maps, linked lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a more useful pattern is declaration of a class inside a function or method. Declaration of a class in the body of another class, as people have noted in other answers, is of little use - yes, it does avoid pollution of the module namespace, but since there_is_ a module namespace at all, a few more names on it do not bother. Even if the extra classes are not intended to be instantiated directly by users of the module, putting then on the module root make their documentation more easily accessible to others.

However, a class inside a function is a completely different creature: It is "declared" and created each time the code containing the class body is run. This gives one the possibility of creating dynamic classes for various uses - in a very simple way. For example, each class created this way is in a different closure, and can have access to different instances of the variables on the containing function.

```
def call_count(func):
    class Counter(object):
       def __init__(self):
           self.counter = 0
       def __repr__(self):
           return str(func)
       def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
           self.counter += 1
           return func(*args, **kw)
    return Counter()
```

And using it on the console:

```
>>> @call_count
... def noop(): pass
...
>>> noop()
>>> noop()
>>> noop.counter
2
>>> noop
<function noop at 0x7fc251b0b578>
```

So, a  simple call_counter decorator could use a static "Counter" class, defined outside the function, and receiving func as a parameter to its constructor - but if you want to tweak other behaviors, like in this example, making repr(func) return the function representation, not the class representation, it is easier to be made this way.
.

Answer (score 1):

"Nested classes" can mean two different things, which can be split into three different categories by intent. The first one is purely stylistic, the other two are used for practical purposes, and are highly dependent on the features language where they are used.

1. Nested class definitions for the sake of creating a new namespace and/or organizing your code better. For example, in Java this is accomplished through the use *static* nested classes, and it is suggested by [the official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) as a way to create more readable and maintainable code, and to logically group classes together. The Zen of Python, however, suggests that you nest code blocks less, thus discouraging this practice.

   `import this`

   In Python you'd much more often see the classes grouped in modules.
2. Putting a class inside another class as part of its interface (or the interface of the instances). First, this interface can be used by the implementation to aid subclassing, for example imagine a nested class `HTML.Node` which you can override in a subclass of `HTML` to alter the class used to create new node instances. Second, this interface might be used by the class/instance users, though this is not that useful unless you are in the third case described below.

   In Python at least, you don't need to nest the definitions to achieve either of those, however, and it's probably very rare. Instead, you might see `Node` defined outside of the class and then `node_factory = Node` in the class definition (or a method dedicated to creating the nodes).
3. Nesting the namespace of the objects, or creating different contexts for different groups of objects. In Java, *non-static* nested classes (called *inner* classes) are bound to an instance of the outer class. This is very useful because it lets you have instances of the inner class that live inside different outer namespaces.

   For Python, consider the `decimal` module. You can create different contexts, and have things like different precisions defined for each context. Each `Decimal` object can assigned a context on creation. This achieves the same as an inner class would, through a different mechanism. If Python supported inner classes, and `Context` and `Decimal` were nested, you'd have `context.Decimal('3')` instead of `Decimal('3', context=context)`.

   You could easily create a metaclass in Python that lets you create nested classes that live inside of an instance, you can even make it produce proper bound and unbound class proxies that support `isinstance` correctly through the use of `__subclasscheck__` and `__instancecheck__`. However, it won't gain you anything over the other simpler ways to achieve the same (like an additional argument to `__init__`). It would only limit what you can do with it, and I have found inner classes in Java very confusing every time I had to use them.